# How to conditionally insert elements into list?

Tags: haskell

Say I have a list of Strings

```
["hello", "xbox", "blue"]
```

And now I want to "insert" (as in create a new immutable list) linefeed characters into the list, but only if the word before ends on a vowel, e.g. a function that creates the following list:

```
["hello", "\n", "xbox", "blue", "\n"]
```

What's the most elegant/direct way of doing this in haskell?

Comment: Use recursion: pattern match on the list, and check if the first element ends in a vowel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be using `do`-notation. `do`-notation on the list monad is a lot like list comprehension, but it also allows you to 'return' multiple elements. Here's my implementation:

```
solution1 :: [String] -> [String]
solution1 strings = do
    str <- strings   -- Go through each element of the list
    if last str `elem` "aeiou"
        then [str, "\n"]   -- 'Replace' that element with the element then a newline
        else [str]         -- Do nothing.
```

But this is a bit of a weird way of going about things, especially if you're a beginner. The usual way would be recursion, so let's do that instead:

```
solution2 :: [String] -> [String]
solution2 []     = [] -- Base case: empty list.
solution2 (x:xs) =    -- Inductive case: non-empty list.
    if last x `elem` "aeiou"
        then x : "\n" : solution2 xs -- Recur, reconstructing as we go.
        else x : solution2 xs        -- Recur, this time with no extra newline.
```

In reality though, these do basically the same thing—`do`-notation on lists is basically just an abstraction of the second method.

**Something to consider:** I used the `last` function, but this will fail on empty strings. How could you fix that?

Comment: I like the monadic version, but my guess is it's a bit slower than the recursive one too... well you simply have to guard against the empty string using a case statement maybe?

Comment: @JohnSmith I would be surprised if the monadic version was too much lower. Also yes, you can guard against that case using `case`. I might be inclined to write a seperate function at that point, however.

Comment: I'd rather see this written with `foldr`, and for it to move the common `x :` outside of the `if`, like this: `foldr (\x acc -> x:if last x \`elem\` "aeiou" then "\n":acc else acc) []`